# libxcrypt "failure token" *0

Tags: passwords

An number of years ago, the libxcrypt project has decided to change the `crypt` interface such that instead of returning a null pointer on failure, it returns a valid string starting with `*`, such as `*0`. They call this a "failure token".

What is the motivation for this?

It seems like an incredibly bad idea to me, because if an application doesn't check for this value, and doesn't notice that the function changed `errno` to `EINVAL`, it will just run with what is *de facto* a really bad hash. Two different passwords passed to `crypt` under the erroneous conditions will both "hash" to the `*0` token, which makes the passwords equivalent. Something thus incorrectly protected with one password can be accessed with any other password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is well documented. To cite from the [man page of crypt(3)](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/blob/develop/doc/crypt.3):

> The behavior of crypt on errors isn't well standardized.  Some implementations simply can't fail (except by crashing the program), others return
> a null pointer or a fixed string.  Most implementations don't set errno,
> but some do.  POSIX specifies returning a null pointer and setting errno,
> but it defines only one possible error, ENOSYS, in the case where crypt
> is not supported at all.  Some older applications are not prepared to
> handle null pointers returned by crypt.  **The behavior described above for
> this implementation, setting errno and returning an invalid hashed
> passphrase different from setting, is chosen to make these applications
> fail closed when an error occurs.**

Comment: Does the implementation ensure that the hash doesn't match in the failed case? That is to say, suppose we hash `crypt(whatever, "*0")`. In that case, we don't want to return `*0`, because the naive program will conclude that there is match. However, the returned string can be perturbed so that it's different from the right argument; is it?

Comment: @Kaz: You asked for the motivation - you got the motivation. What you ask now is a specific question on how this is implemented. But just read on in the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/libcrypt1-dev/crypt_rn.3.en.html): *"The behavior described above for this implementation, setting errno and returning an invalid hashed passphrase __different from setting__, is chosen to make these applications fail closed when an error occurs."*

Comment: I see, thanks. They are using the word *setting* for the second argument.